# Should I test inheritance and implementation?

Tags: unit-testing, inheritance, implements

Are unit tests supposed to check if a class implements an interface using reflection (same question with inheritance)? If no, why?

If the implementation is removed, the code may still compile, and the tests might still be successful (it depends on what the code does).

Answer (score 1):

Unit tests should test anything that may not work. If the programming language doesn't ensure a class implements all methods in a contract, then you'd probably want to check this in tests.

Answer (score 0):

You should test **what is important** to your code.  Things like inheritance, interfaces and the like are at *best* **implementation details** which should be hidden away from the raw data result.

That is to say, if your code passes without the inheritance, it probably didn't need the inheritance and it should be cleaned up as cruft.

Comment: Let's say the project is a library, class `A` and class `B` implements both a specific interface  `I`. `A` and `B` can be used as `I` by clients, until someone decides `B` doesn't implements `I` anymore. Without a specific test, the code would still compile and the tests would still pass. Then I guess unit tests should check this.

Comment: Sounds like someone didn't really follow good protocol and rely on `I` as the abstraction and relied on `B` as a concrete implementation instead.  You can't really test for that since the code didn't make any guarantees around the stability of `B`.

Answer (score 0):

A few times in my career I had a situation where I wrote this kind of unit test, mostly for testing conventions.

E.g. there was an implicit assumption that all unit tests should inherit from BaseTest (although technically everything worked fine without this, we wanted that for the sake of coherence) and we had a unit test that enforced exactly that :).

So yes, that makes perfect sense, if necessary.